# How to draw charts in html page using javascript and the data should be fetched from excel using js

Tags: javascript, html, excel, charts

I have a requirement to fetch data from excel and draw charts in html page using javascript. Is there any best tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[d3js](http://d3js.org/)**. They have good documentation and tutorials available and have methods to fetch data from excel and draw charts using them.